# Microsoft Word 2010 cannot get blank document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010, document-management

Whenever I open Microsoft Word 2010, an old document opens up. It's the same one all the time.

And even if I go and try to open a new document, this same document is alway there.

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, all Word documents have a default template.  The "normal.dotm" template is  a blank document which comes up when you start a new document.  Check to see if you mistakenly overwrote the normal template with a previous document.  Here is some information about Word 2010 templates:

http://www.laptopmag.com/advice/tips/change-your-default-template-in-word.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As David suggest in another answer, you have likely overwritten the default template. The simplest way to restore it is:

- Close Word
- Delete the normal.dotm (for Word 2007 and newer) or normal.dot (for 2003 and older) file.
- Open Word and a new default template with default settings will be created.

This [article](http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow_viewer/0,3253,l%253D252324%2526a%253D252321%2526po%253D5,00.asp?p=n) describes how to do that in detail.